# A coin is tossed 4 times

Tags: probability

The result is either (H) or  (T).
 Define the events

1. D: ”The fourth toss is tails” and
2. F:
   ”Heads and tails alternate”.

Additionally,
determine: $$D ∩ F$$

Now for $P (D)$ there are 8 possibilities so then: $$P (D) = 1/(2^8) $$ but my friend said that it needs to be: $$8/(2^8) $$
Is that right? If so, why?

**Edit**:tried to make it more clear. I already know how to get P (F) and $$D ∩ F$$. My main confusion is just with P (D)

Comment: $P(D)=0.5$ (only look at the $4$-th toss) and $P(D\cap F)=2^{-4}$ (only HTHT is possible).

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking. $P(D)$ or $P(D \cap F)$? Or something else?

Comment: @drhab but why is that the only one? Can't you also get (H H H T), (HTTT), (HHTT) and etc?

Comment: @HartoSaarinen I am asking for P (D)

Comment: I read "alternate" as HTHT or THTH.

Comment: @gigantea8 $P(D)$ is simply $1/2$.

Comment: @drhab then P (F) = 0.5 not P (D), no?

Comment: Can you explain why you think that $P(F)=0.5$?

Comment: @drhab wait I was wrong sorry! But I still don't understand why the other tosses don't matter

Comment: If you are talking about $D$ (fourth toss a tail) think of it like this: there are two equiprobable possibilities (head or tail) and their sum is $1$, so both equalize $0.5$. The $4$-th toss has nothing to do with the other tosses (independence). They have no influence at all on what happens at the $4$-th toss. So it is enough to focus on the $4$-th toss.

Comment: @drhab aha. That makes it very clear for me. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @gigantea8 Please accept my answer if you like it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$P(D)$ is $1/2$
Now let us see how...
By Laplace's law, Probability can be expressed as  **the ratio of the number of favourable events to the total number of events.**
Now if you know how to count permutations, you will see that there are clearly $2×2×2×1$ favourable events and $2×2×2×2$ total number of events. Taking the ratio, you get $1/2$

Let us now find $P(F)$

For F, there are two favourable cases, namely, HTHT,THTH. And the total cases remain same.
So, $P(F)=1/2^3$

Finally, $$P(D \cap F)=P(D)×P(F)=1/2^4$$

**EDIT**: Another way of finding $P(D)$
Clearly $P(D)=1/2$ because what we get on coins 1,2 and 3 has no effect on what we get on 4(independant events) and also there are no restrictions on the outcome of 1,2,3.

**2nd EDIT**  Let us define four events:.
1-Getting either a head or a tail on tossing coin 1.
2-Getting either a head or a tail on tossing coin 2.
3.Getting either a head or a tail on tossing coin 3.
4. Getting a tail on tossing coin 4.
NB All these events are independent. We are not tossing the other coins when we are tossing some $i$th coin.
Therefore, clearly $P(D)=1•1•1•1/2=1/2$

Comment: I would suggest a minor improvement: The ratio of the number of favourable events to the total number of events is not *the* definition of probability. It's Laplace's law in the case that all outcomes are equally likely.

Answer (score 2):

First, $P(D)=\frac12$, because other tosses do not matter.

For $P(F)$, we see that there are $2^4$ possible outcomes when tossing a coin 4 times. Of these, only 2 are good: THTH and HTHT. This makes a total of $P(F)=\frac{2}{2^4}=\frac{1}{2^3}=\frac{1}{8}$.

Now we combine $D$ and $F$. Then, only HTHT is left. So we have $P(D\cap F)=\frac{1}{2^4}=\frac{1}{16}$.

Comment: The coin is tossed 4 times.

Comment: OMG, thanks.... I'll edit my answer. I somehow got stuck on that 8 in the question.

Comment: I would rather say: "if we combine $D$ and $F$" instead of "...$P(D)$ and $P(F)$".

Comment: Good point, thanks.